# Spring Boot and JWT - JSESSIONID allows REST request without need for JWT?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, cookies, jwt

I have implemented `JWT` authorization within my `Spring Boot REST API` using `Auth0`.

It is generally working as expected, however I have noticed a strange issue when testing in `POSTMAN`.

When I successfully authenticate *any one* request, e.g. a GET request using the Bearer JWT token from `Auth0`, I then get the following `Cookie` populated in all my other requests:

[image]

Now, with this `JESSIONID` cookie I am able to perform my other `REST` requests with *no JWT Token*?

Why is this? It does not seem secure, I would expect a `JWT` to need to be passed for every REST request?

My Spring `SecurityConfig` for reference:

```
/**
 * Configures our application with Spring Security to restrict access to our API endpoints.
 */
@EnableWebSecurity

    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Value("${auth0.audience}")
        private String audience;

        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
        private String issuer;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            /*
            This is where we configure the security required for our endpoints and setup our app to serve as
            an OAuth2 Resource Server, using JWT validation.
            */
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/users/**").authenticated()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/users/**").authenticated()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/users/**").authenticated()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/users/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        }

        @Bean
        JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
            /*
            By default, Spring Security does not validate the "aud" claim of the token, to ensure that this token is
            indeed intended for our app. Adding our own validator is easy to do:
            */

            NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

            jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

            return jwtDecoder;
        }


        @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 ways to manage session in Spring Security,

1. always – a session will always be created if one doesn't already exist
2. ifRequired – a session will be created only if required (default)
3. never – the framework will never create a session itself but it will use one if it already exists
4. stateless – no session will be created or used by Spring Security

So looking at your configuration, it seems that your application is using 2nd option which is "ifRequired" and it creates the session and if request comes with existing sessionId, it allows the user to access the resource because that user is already authorized.

So if you want your application to be completely stateless and no session should be created, you should use the last option which is stateless.
So to make it stateless, change your configuration to,

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/**").authenticated()
        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**").authenticated()
        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/users/**").authenticated()
        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/users/**").authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! In regards to http.cors().and().csrf().disable() - does this make my code less secure? Also - do you reccomend using a completely stateless session?

Comment: See if this can help you in this regard,
https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/05/stateless.html

Comment: I can confirm that this has worked. This is also a more secure way as a jwt must be passed every time?